# how to set selected rows in flash datagrid (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, datagrid

I want to select multiple rows in current result set in DataGrid in flash as3.
I tried to do it like that:

```
this.dataGrid.selectedItems = _selectedElements[index];
```

where `_selectedElements` is an array that holds results of prevoius selection on results page gathered like that:

```
_selectedElements[index] = this.dataGrid.selectedItems;
```

**`_selectedElements` has correct values (`checked`) and I'm sure that the problem is with datagrid component.**

Does anybody have a clue how to make it work?

Comment: Spark or MX? what particular version of the SDK, have you tried drilling into DataGrid (in FlashBuilder/Eclipse Ctrl+Shift+T then type DataGrid drop some breakpoints in the set selectedItems, follow the path of execution using F6 to step over function calls, F5 to step into the functions to further trace the execution).

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood you question first so I edited my answer. You can set selected rows like this:

myDataGrid.selectedIndices = [3,4,5,6];

Answer (score 0):

To select a multiple rows, you have to write a coding in for loop using rows and columns. And by giving count eg.rows+1, rows-1 you can access the rows. same for column also. pls try this and let me know if you have any doubt.